# Is there a way to split list items into single digits keeping them in the same position on the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm iplementing the [Luhn Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) where you have to multiply every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s second-to-last digit, and then add those products’ digits together.

I already extracted a list of odd numbers and multiplied it:

- `CardNumber:    4003600000000014`
- `oddNumbrs:     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 4]`
- `oddNumbrs * 2: [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 8]`

My problem lies with every 2 digit number that might appear since I want to add those digits together as:

- `oddNumbrs2digits: [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 8]`

How can I go about doing this?

**Edit:** Found a possible solution I don't know how convoluted or correct it is but it does the job:

```
oddNumbrs2digits = list(map(int, "".join(map(str,oddNumbrs2))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the list, transform the int to str and then flatten the values:

```
oddNumbrs2 = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 8]
[int(e) for i in oddNumbrs2 for e in str(i)]

[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oddNumbrs2digits = [int(char) for char in ''.join(str(digit * 2) for digit in oddNumbrs)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an appropriate multiplication function to apply to the odd numbers.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> def luhnmult(x):
...    x2 = 2*x
...    return [int(d) for d in str(x2)]
...
>>> odd_numbers = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 4]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(luhnmult, odd_numbers)))
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 8]
```

The combination of `chain.from_iterable` and `map` is similar to a function often referred to as `concatMap` in other languages. `luhnmult` always returns a list of the digits of your product; `map` produces a sequence of such lists, which `chain.from_iterable` flattens into a single sequence of digits. `list` then creates a list from that sequence.

```
>>> def concatmap(f, xs):
...    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(f, xs)))
>>> concatmap(luhnmult, odd_numbers)
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 8]
```